# include (url) : filed to open stream : connection refused

Tags: php, include, localhost

I have set in php.ini the `allow_url_include = On` and I have to files on localhost:

*a.php*:

```
<?php
$var = "var1";
//echo $var
```

*b.php*:

```
<?php
include "http://127.0.0.1/a.php";
echo $var
```

which gives error (on execution of *b.php*):
Undefined variable: var in /var/www/html/b.php on line 5

all files works by itself, but the `b.php` cannot include the variable from the `a.php`, but why, when the url_include is allowed?

Comment: _“but why”_ - **because** you are making your request via HTTP, and not the file system. PHP gets _parsed_ when you request this via HTTP, so you only get the actual _output_ of this script, not the code.

Comment: @CBroe so I can only include `html` (output) and not `php` (code) ? by url?

Comment: If you want to include the code, then you have to go via the file system, not HTTP.

Comment: By include I usually want some functionality (e.g. classes or functions), but that is not possible via http (as you said). Which means I can only include html output. But why would I want to include html? It does not add me anything useable (in ohter words, what is the proper case I would want to include html from outside?)

Comment: _“By include I usually want some functionality (e.g. classes or functions), but that is not possible via http (as you said)”_ - it _is_ possible, when you make the remote server return the PHP code in actual text form, _instead of_ parsing it. Rename your `a.php` to `a.txt`, and see what happens then.

Comment: But this is usually not _done_, because now you’d be executing code that comes from a different source - so if you do not have _absolute_ control over this source, then you should not even think about doing anything like this. If I was in control of this (on an actual remote server), then I could easily switch `$var = "var1";` with some code that deletes all files in the current directory, or something like that. You probably would not want to execute that on your system any more then.